# What’s a “handegg”?

Tags: etymology, slang, history, connotation, winterfest

### What’s a *handegg*?

**NOTE**: This question is primarily related to the etymology of a compound noun which is not in [The Dictionary](http://www.oed.com).

There is a hat this year called “Handegg”, given out for a posting that reaches a score of +7.  But here’s the problem: the word *handegg* does not occur in the *Oxford English Dictionary*!  Neither does *hand-egg* nor *hand egg*.

Given that absence, I would like to know:

1. What is exact etymology and history of *handegg* as documented by reputable scholarly sources?
2. What is the primary sense of *handegg*, and are there any auxiliary senses or attendant connotations?
3. Is *handegg* a word used in only one region or [sociolect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolect), or is it a word that most native speakers of English the whole wide world around would reasonably be expected know?
4. Is *handegg* an inventive substitution for some other, better-known term?
5. If *handegg* has a primary sense that is not shall we say “off-color”, does the word also some sort of *double entendre* whereby it also means something risqué?

Although that looks like five questions, it really is only one. To be accepted, only the first question needs answering. The others are just elaborations on the first.

---

**Background**: I’m asking because I kept reading *handegg* as *handbag*, which I genuinely thought it was until only a couple minutes ago when I was disabused of this misreading, but that only brought new mysteries.  In the [accent of Green Bay, Wisconsin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Midwest_American_English), *bag* and *egg* can seem to have the same vowel due to the *bag–beg* merger, so maybe this is how I misread it.

Comment: You worked hard on that question. +1.

Comment: I thought handeggs were just the more expensive version of nesteggs- according to the old saying, "An egg in the hand is worth two in the nest."

Comment: [This could have easily been solved with Google.](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=handegg)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Wrong: Google is not a “reputable scholarly source” as specifically requested and required by the question. Neither is Urban Dictionary.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: depends what you mean by "solved". tchrist could very easily have determined by that search what the word means, and confirmed by looking at the hat design that this is indeed what the hat is intended to reference. But that doesn't provide the history that tchrist desires. You personally might prefer questions to show a bit more research than *just* checking the OED, but I don't think that simple search alone turns up the top answer here, so it's still only a part-solution.

Comment: ... ooh, it's on the second page. But who the heck makes it to the second page of a Google search? That's an absurd expectation. This question is now on the first page, so asking it has made that history easier for others to find in future.

Comment: Ever since reading this question I've been annoying the crap out of all my friends by trying to convince them that it's handegg that they're referring to.

Comment: **What great etymological question is there?** Its a joke about "American Football". Except rather than kicking a ***ball* with a *foot*** play is done by holding an ***egg* in the *hand***. Children understand this joke.

Comment: All the answers on this page are clearly nonsense. It should be obvious to anyone that [this is what _handegg_ is](http://www.thewestonmercury.co.uk/polopoly_fs/1.869883!/image/2340818001.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_490/2340818001.jpg).

Answer (score 169, accepted):

[CBS Sports](http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/eye-on-football/24614305/just-because-why-do-we-call-it-football-and-not-hand-egg) has this nice article explaining the origin of the word, including a newspaper snippet from 1909:

[image: New York Times snippet]

> #### “Hand-Egg,” Not Football.
>
> *To the Editor of The New York Times:*
>
> Football is certainly a misnomer, for the game is played not with the feet but with the hands, and the ball is not a ball but an egg.
>
> I propose that the game be played with the feet and with a ball, or else that it be called “hand-egg.”
>
> OBSERVER.
> New York, Nov. 7, 1909.

Hand-egg is the proposed word for what has been named *football* when describing a sport in which an egg is moved using one's hands, instead of an activity where a *ball* is moved with one’s *feet*.

Comment: Verified not fake: http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9407E0D7123EE733A2575AC0A9679D946897D6CF&module=Search&mabReward=relbias%3As

Comment: I had no idea this joke was that old - but then again, I thought it came from The Simpsons! +1 for educational value.

Comment: How come you say “correct”?  Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Elongated balls are indeed balls according to Oxford. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ball Also I cannot find a clear and reliable source but most website point to a length of around 11.5 inches (12 being a foot in imperial system). It's then normal that it be called a foot-ball. American Football was named after its ball, not after the action. By your logic we should call soccer ("football") "feetball" instead because both feet ared used when playing football.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: Meh, [I don't really trust that website too much](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212716/name-for-fine-hair-on-human-skin/212718#comment453159_212718)

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: Pretty impressive football player if you're kicking it with both feet at the same time

Comment: American football was Rugby (Union) football long before the now-official size and shape of the ball was established. And the first games of American football were played with a round ball. The elongated, then pointed, ball developed over time as drop-kicks and laterals gave way to the forward pass. The idea that the game was named "football" for its foot-long ball is nonsense.

Comment: Not that it matters for the purpose of the joke, but isn't it called "football" because you aren't on horseback?

Comment: "Correct word" is certainly strong phrasing. I've only ever heard *hand-egg* used derisively, generally by people from countries where football refers to what Americans call soccer. There aren't any coaches going onto the field yelling at the quarterback to throw the hand-egg.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: "correct word" is just following the facetious tone/assumptions of the original 1909 letter.

Comment: @SteveJessop That may be, but is that worth possibly misleading people who don't see the deeper context? Saying something is the "correct word" here, on EL&U, has the potential to reach quite a few people. I say let's leave the joke in the letter and make the answer serious.

Comment: By this notion, Soccer should be called "Flop-Writhe" since most action seems to be players faking injuries to get a penalty.

Comment: @Oldcat: clearly you don't understand the sport in the least. Only one of the 22 players on the field is writhing around, the others are engaged in the far more important activities of gesticulating wildly, gazing imploringly at the ref, shrugging their shoulders, offering a hand to the "injured" player to shake, etc. It's all about the combined effect on the ref, those who just flop and writhe are ignoring that it's a team game. The same principle is starting to take hold in the NFL of course, under the current PI rules.

Comment: As an uncultured American, I admit the nuances might escape me from time to time.

Comment: @Oldcat: same thing for me when I started watching the NFL. I picked the Saints to support in 2002-ish, so it was a couple of years before I realised the object of the game *isn't* to go 8-8 and miss the playoffs. Now I understand the object is to go 8-8 and make the playoffs anyway.

Comment: @SteveJessop [The IT Crowd on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f27IqVo5-Oc)

Answer (score 96):

It's a football reference.

- The hat is a football helmet
- The football is egg-shaped and held in your hands
- A touchdown is worth 7 points (including the obligatory point-after-touchdown)

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handegg):

> From hand +‎ egg, by contrast to football meaning “soccer”, with the notion that the respective sports are “neither foot nor ball” due to the predominant use of the hands and the elongated form of the ball.

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=handegg):

> American football. As opposed to football/soccer, where players actually kick a ball with their feet, American football involves players carrying an egg-shaped object in their hands.

[image: Comparison of football and handegg]

Comment: Aren’t balls and eggs like um opposites? As in ♂ for balls and ♀ for eggs?  Was this why it was chosen?

Comment: It's just the shape: the US football is not shaped like a ball, but more like an egg (i.e. elongated). And you cradle it, as if it's fragile.

Comment: Is this a Canadian term then, or is it a US term, too?

Comment: I think it's a joke term. I've never heard it used seriously. But many of the hats are based on jokes or memes.

Comment: A touchdown is worth six points. I've only ever watched like three games and even I know that.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 It is seriously employed as a term of derision by followers of real sports which do not require armor.

Comment: @RegDwigнt [According to this article](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/0ap3000000379874/article/eight-extra-points-missed-in-preseason-action), in the NFL something like 99% of extra point attempts are successful, meaning that for all practical purposes the touchdown's value is 7 points. The hand-egg hat requires 7 votes. Other forms of the game hand-egg may or may not have different success rates for extra points, but that has no bearing on how this hat relates to football.

Comment: Actually, Aussie Rules Football is "Handegg", The US Football has points on it, which eggs do not have.

Comment: For what it's worth, the image in this answer directly inspired the [hat idea and design](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/handegg). The trigger was indeed a reference to the seemingly arbitrary score that results from a successful touchdown + extra point kick. (Note, it's also possible to get 8 points with a two-point conversion, but there's no hat for that.)

Comment: @JonEricson great! So can I get a Eureka on ELU for finding that? ;p

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: The touchdown is strictly **six** points. The ability to go for a two-point conversion doesn't make the touchdown worth eight points either, and neither is it `6 + ( 1 * <success rate of NFL PATs> ) + ( 2 * <success rate of NFS conversions> )`. It's 6.

Comment: @DevSolar That's one way to look at it. Tell you what. Get the SE folks to change the number of votes required for the handegg hat and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

A *handegg* is an American football.

It doesn't (often) touch the foot and isn't (much of) a ball shape.

Answer (score 15):

[Handegg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handegg) is a village in Switzerland, in the Canton of Bern, [somewhat near Lucerne](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Handegg,+3864+Guttannen,+Switzerland).  Beautiful place, I am sure, but just why they named that hat after it escapes me.

Comment: With my vote.. have a hand-egg helmet :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to wear it if I visit Switzerland :).  Is it sad that this little joke is my most upvoted answer in the network?

Comment: Only a little. My most upvoted answer is a [piece of code that doesn't work](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23765/15394) ;)

Comment: Note that in German the syllables would be "Han" (pronounced "hahn") and "degg" - thus, the pronunciation is ever-so-slightly different that the English "hand-egg". Ah, America and Switzerland - two countries separated by several thousand miles, an ocean, a couple of intervening countries, a bunch of mountains, some pretty big rivers, and mutually incomprehensible languages.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Actually, the syllables would be _Hand - egg_ because it is most like a compound word (Hand + Ecke). This is corroborated by a nearby place's name, _Gerstenegg_, which you'd analyse as a compound of Gerste + Ecke (barley + corner). In Standard German, Handegg would therefore have a glottal stop between the syllables. However, I'm not sure whether its Swiss pronunciation and English _handegg_ have glottal stops.

Answer (score 10):

[Handegg](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handegg):

Etymology

> - From hand +‎ egg, by deliberate contrast to football meaning “soccer”, emphasizing the use of the hands and an elongated rather than round ball.

handegg (countable and uncountable, plural handeggs)

> - (slang, uncountable) A humorous term for the game of American football, or for any other sport called “football” that uses a prolate spheroid instead of a ball and in which the hands may be used, such as Canadian football or rugby.

(from en.wiktionary.org)

Comment: Is this a regionalism?

Comment: Not in the US.,,

Comment: @tchrist: If it's any "ism" it's probably anti-americanism. I've seen it used (and have used it myself) in many online forums where the membership includes a large number of people from the US but they're not the overwhelming majority. I've seen it used by Malaysians, Indians, Brazilians, Germans, Brits etc.

Comment: Note that depending on the forum/community, the use of the word "handegg" can devolve into either playful banter or heated flamewars.

Answer (score 6):

It's an American football.  It could also be related to Rugby football as rugby players are jovially known as "egg-chasers" in Britain.

Comment: This Brit has never heard of "egg-chasers", but admittedly does not follow Rugby in either code.

Comment: Except you don't wear a helmet in Rugby. Out of interest, if you search "egg-chaser" on google, the first link is urban dictionary, the next few are unrelated, then you arrive at this page.

Comment: This Brit has very definitely heard "egg-chasers" as a light-hearted derisory term for players of Rugby Football, particularly from fans of Association Football.

Comment: Just to join in on the "vote", this Brit has never heard of "egg-chasers" either. I (used to) follow rugby, but if it's mostly used derisively by <strike>hooligans</strike> association football fans, that makes sense as I don't follow football.

Answer (score 4):

Blame the English, they invented the names for all of the sports derived from soccer.

Association football (soccer) came first.
Then the English named the next game rugby football, after the town in England that changed the rules of soccer.

Then others derived games from rugby, still keeping the football name.

- Rugby Football League
- Australian Football League
- American Football

If you're English and you want to whine about the names your country gave the sport, then harden up and go play something with some contact in it.